# Lookup based on criteria in named range, then concatenate results

Tags: excel, vba

we have an interesting formula to figure out.

First, we count the following, where MYDATE needs to fall between the two dates. REGISTER.DT and EXIT.DT are both named ranges A:A and B:B, MYDATE is a named range that points at C1.

> =SUMPRODUCT(--(REGISTER.DT<=MYDATE)*(EXIT.DT>=MYDATE))

and another example, with more criteria (Sometimes up to 5 criteria)

> =SOMPRODUCT(--(AANM.DT>=DT.START)*(AANM.DT<=DT.EIND)*(TYPE.TXT=I8))

Now for the question. The above formule returns 2 (so it finds two dates)

We now want to find and show these dates in a concatenated string

I have been fiddling with a VBA function StringConcat that I found online, but i doesnt skip zeros (converts all to string), but also doenst understand named ranges.

Anyone have hint? or a Matrix function lookup that could work?

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a User Defined Function that will work based on your design.  Feed in two matching arrays in the first two parameters, then the key date in the third.  You will get back the list of REGISTER dates that mark the beginning of range(s) holding that key date:

```
Option Explicit

Function DateCAT(RegisterRng As Range, ExitRng As Range, MyDt As Date) As String
Dim DtARR As Variant, D As Long

If RegisterRng.Cells.Count <> ExitRng.Cells.Count Then
    DateCAT = "date ranges do not match"
    Exit Function
End If

DtARR = Union(RegisterRng, ExitRng)

For D = LBound(DtARR) To UBound(DtARR)
    If DtARR(D, 1) <= MyDt And DtARR(D, 2) >= MyDt Then
        DateCAT = DateCAT & ", " & DtARR(D, 1)
    End If
Next D

If DateCAT = "" Then
    DateCAT = "none"
Else
    DateCAT = Mid(DateCAT, 3, Len(DateCAT))
End If

End Function
```

**=DATECAT(REGISTER.DT, EXIT.DT, MYDATE)**

[image]

By the way, the formulas I used for REGISTER.DT and EXIT.DT are dynamic.

**=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),)**

**=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B),)**

============================
This version is like COUNTIFS(), you put the range to return from first, then list pairs of values... a range, then a test on that range, then another optional range and test, up to 5 total.

**=DATECAT(Values, TstRng1, Test1, OptTstRng2, OptTest2, OptTstRng3, OptTest3)**

```
Option Explicit

Function DateCAT(RegisterRng As Range, RNG1 As Range, TST1 As String, _
    Optional RNG2 As Range, Optional TST2 As String, _
    Optional RNG3 As Range, Optional TST3 As String, _
    Optional RNG4 As Range, Optional TST4 As String, _
    Optional RNG5 As Range, Optional TST5 As String) As String

Dim D As Long, Bad As Boolean, i As Long

D = RegisterRng.Cells.Count

If RNG1.Cells.Count <> D Then Bad = True
If Not RNG2 Is Nothing Then If RNG2.Cells.Count <> D Then Bad = True
If Not RNG3 Is Nothing Then If RNG3.Cells.Count <> D Then Bad = True
If Not RNG4 Is Nothing Then If RNG4.Cells.Count <> D Then Bad = True
If Not RNG5 Is Nothing Then If RNG5.Cells.Count <> D Then Bad = True

If Bad Then
    DateCAT = "data ranges do not match"
    Exit Function
End If

For i = 1 To RNG1.Cells.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RNG1.Cells(i), TST1) = 0 Then Bad = True

    If Not RNG2 Is Nothing Then If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RNG2.Cells(i), TST2) = 0 Then Bad = True
    If Not RNG3 Is Nothing Then If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RNG3.Cells(i), TST3) = 0 Then Bad = True
    If Not RNG4 Is Nothing Then If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RNG4.Cells(i), TST4) = 0 Then Bad = True
    If Not RNG5 Is Nothing Then If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RNG5.Cells(i), TST5) = 0 Then Bad = True

    If Not Bad Then DateCAT = DateCAT & ", " & RegisterRng.Cells(i).Value
    Bad = False
Next i

If DateCAT = "" Then
    DateCAT = "none"
Else
    DateCAT = Mid(DateCAT, 3, Len(DateCAT))
End If

End Function
```

Important: When checking on a named range (one cell, with 1 value) you need to enter TST1 etc as operater & named range: `">"&MYCELL`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry. ANd this is already vry helpful ... BUT what would we do if we have multiple variables to check on, including dates and non-dates, and larger than etc. Our full formulas (for counting are: > =SOMPRODUCT(--(AANM.DT>=DT.START)*(AANM.DT<=DT.EIND)*(TYPE.TXT=I8)) AND > =SOMPRODUCT(--(AANM.DT>=DT.START)*(AANM.DT<=DT.EIND)*(--(TRIAGE.DT>=DT.START)*(TRIAGE.DT<=DT.EIND)))

Comment: I have discovered the problem lies in the array formula not enjoying the named ranges. Now how do I create a simple function that updates a named range into something an array formula does like

Comment: Then I can put P() around all named ranges and continue (assuming P is the function to convert named range)

Comment: I've added a second version above.  It works like COUNTIFS(), and allows up to 5 "tests".

Comment: Super. haha. How cool. I will try tomorrow when I access the dataset. Would it also work on named ranges?

Comment: Yes, as long as the ranges all are the same number of cells.  Watch what happens if define ranges of different lengths.   Be sure to upvote if this will work for you, or you can take it from here.